# Code First Migrations Not Working

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

FINAL EDIT:
Well, it's good to know that the good folks at Microsoft (marketing execs excluded) are geniuses, even if I'm not. Remember, kids: If you want to change your data model, define your properties with a getter/setter, not as a public field. Duh... 8-D

EDIT 4:
I'm glad I didn't waste anyone's time too much with this, as I think I have this solved (though I haven't fully checked out whether that's true yet).

Here's the deal: I DEFINED MY SO-CALLED NEW PROPERTY AS SIMPLY A STRING, WITH NO GET/SET! Call me bad names if you wish. There is no cached version of my model, but it was fun pointing my finger anyway. Silly me. My ego definitely loves to complain.

I will come back and post a final closing to this post after I have fully verified that everything is going to work okay.

Original Post:
I am using Entity Framework and have my projects structured so that my data context is in one project and my model is in another. There was a time when I was able to use Migrations and it worked, but now it does not work. Also, if I try to add a property to my model and manually create it in my database, the new column is simply ignored. Somehow I had a migration that I did not need and Migrations refused to let me go any further, so I set out to start from scratch with my existing database. Somewhere along the way I upgraded all my projects to Entity Framework Version 6.0. After that, my application still works but I can make no modifications to my data model.

I tried this:
http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/03/ef-4-3-migrations-and-existing-database/
and this:
[How to use migrations on an existing db in production created using Entity Framework 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10602680/how-to-use-migrations-on-an-existing-db-in-production-created-using-entity-frame)

Steps I've taken:

1. Deleted my _MigrationHistory table from the database and Migrations folder from my project that contains the data context
2. Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyProjectWithDataContext (successful, and -Force wasn't necessary)
3. Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges -ProjectName MyProjectWithDataContext (successful)
4. Update-Database -ProjectName MyProjectWithDataContext

From there, if I change my model and generate another migration, the Up() and Down() have no generated code in them. Therefore, running Update-Database does nothing useful.

I also tried these steps and also specified the StartUpProjectName for the project containing the connection string in each, but that didn't help either.

I tried deleting the database and allowing it to be regenerated (which is not what I want). Even in this scenario new migrations did nothing.

Help?

EDIT:
I've now moved my model into the same assembly as my DbContext. However, the same situation after deleting my Migrations folder and truncating the _MigrationHistory table:

1. Enable-Migrations -ProjectName MyProjectWithDataContextAndModel -StartUpProjectName MyProjectWithConnectionString
2. Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges -ProjectName MyProjectWithDataContextAndModel -StartUpProjectName MyProjectWithConnectionString
3. Update-Database -ProjectName MyProjectWithDataContextAndModel -StartUpProjectName MyProjectWithConnectionString (this successfully puts an entry into the _MigrationHistory table)
4. Add a property to one of my model classes
5. Add-Migration AddProperty -ProjectName MyProjectWithDataContextAndModel -StartUpProjectName MyProjectWithConnectionString (this results once again in empty Up() and Down() code)

Surely this is a very, very common scenario, having Migrations break and needing to get back in the saddle.

EDIT 2:
Okay, so I deleted my database and allowed Code First to generate a new one by creating an initial migration and then running Update-Database. I then added a property to one of my model classes and decorated it with the [REQUIRED] attribute and rebuilt my Solution. From there I ran Add-Migration and again an empty Up() and Down().

This puts me in a situation where I can do no development, with deadlines looming, unable to change my data model whatsoever. To quote Chris Farley: FOR THE LOVE OF GOD...PLEASE HELP! :-)

EDIT 3:
Well, I decided to see what would happen if I deleted the database and then had EF regenerate it WITH the new property defined in my model. In other words, I added the new property to my model FIRST, and then it was only AFTER THAT that I caused EF to regenerate the database.

Guess what? The new property was not in the regenerated database. I am not a Code First guru, but it's becoming very clear that my code files are not being used by EF at all. Somewhere is a cached version of my model that's being used to regenerate the database.

Comment: Are you sure you have automatic migrations turned off in your configuration?

Comment: Yes, the auto-generated Configuration file does that for me.

Comment: @GregoryShields Welcome to StackOverflow. If you found the answer, you should post it as an Answer, instead of editing the question and title with SOLVED. That's forum style; this is StackOverflow where we do things better. :)  See the Help link in the top right for more on how to use StackOverflow well.